# Vim not reading TypeScript file

Tags: typescript, vim, ionic-framework

I recently have started playing around with [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and ran their `ionic start` command after generating a new project.

I noticed that when opening any of the TypeScript files ionic generated in vim, the contents of the file is: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

However, if I open the file in sublime text or `cat` the the file I get the actual contents as I should.

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I did install [typescript-vim](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim), however that doesn't seem to have helped. Vim seems to think it's an `xml` file, however in my vim footer it is indicating `typescript`.

Any thoughts on how I can actually open and edit `TypeScript` files in vim?

Comment: Did you add the expected configuration to your vimrc ?
` autocmd FileType typescript :set makeprg=tsc` aims to map the tsc files for the compiler.
You may need `filetype plugin on` and `filetype plugin indent on
` to allow vim to look for indentation plugin

Comment: Thanks @LLenain.  Yes, I have the `autocmd FileType typescript: set makeprg=tsc` in my `.vimrc`.  Alos, `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`.  I noticed I can open the file then run `:make` and it will compile into a `.js` file that I can then open.

Answer (score 5):

In my case this ended up being a line in my `.vimrc` I had for formatting XML files.

Removing this line, enabled the file to load properly:

```
au FileType xml exe ":silent 1,$!xmllint --format --recover - 2>/dev/null"
```